# Three.js: vertexNormals of CircleGeometry looks inverse on r57

Tags: three.js

VertexNormals of CircleGeometry looks inverse.
If I use computeVertexNormals(), it is fixed.
I'm using r57 and confirmed with Firefox19 and IE9+ChromeFrame26.

If it is already reported, ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed. The vertex normals and UVs for `CircleGeometry` in three.js r.57 are incorrect.

Fixed in r.58dev: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/3279

Comment: Thanks! The helper in the picture is easy to understand.